# How to extract values from array for printing

Tags: php, arrays, printing

I am new to php and trying to accomplish something that must be easy but for whatever reason I cannot find the answer through a search.

Basically I have an array that contains a few items.  I want to print them out in a list but I don't want the array arrows.

Example: using `print_r($_SESSION[species]);` 
gives:

```
Array ( [0] => value1 [1] => value2 [2] => value3 [3] => value4 [4] => )
```

but I want just:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you want [implode](http://php/net/implode). And make sure you quote your array keys: `$_SESSION['species']`.

Comment: you can iterate through an array with a loop (for, foreach, while, pick one) and print out the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...or you could be simpler than the example above, and do a foreach

```
<?php

foreach($_SESSION['species'] as $value)
{
  echo $value."<br />";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. OK so how could I reverse the list.  I.e. I want the last value to be at the top of the list.

Answer (score 4):

You can implode the array

```
$impl=implode("\n",$_SESSION[species]);
echo $impl
```

Will give you

```
value1
value2
value3
```

This will only insert newlines in HTML source.
If you want html linebreaks use

```
implode("<br />",$tmp);
```